# Simplify huge output or using the output without showing it in full

Tags: differential-equations, output-formatting, variable-definitions

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations. It works fine but Mathematica creates a huge output, which, when shown in full, results in a file size about 100 mb. Using Simplify doesn't work because of a time value problem.
Is there another way to use the calculated constants C1 to C12 as variables than open the full output and replacing the arrow operator with an equal sign? Because the huge output really slows down further operations.
Or how could I solve the Simplify problem? FullSimplify takes so much time, that I don't think it will work.

I am using version 8 by the way.

Thank you for your help.

[image: large output box]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include Code, not Pictures.

Comment: Your second question is addressed in the Scope/Basic usage section of the Solve documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a semicolon at the end of your command will suppress its output.

```
result = Solve[...];
```

The result is saved in the variable `result` for further processing. You can get the constants by, for example,

```
constant1 = C1 /. result;
```